# libGDX build fail for java desktop flappy bird clone

Tags: java, intellij-idea, libgdx, flappy-bird-clone

TL/DR: hey guys, trying to make flappy bird clone with java/libGDX/intelliJ (following along with youtube tutorial). when i try to generate in libGDX, i get the following message:

(btw ran libGDX with only desktop selected, tried going into advance options but doesnt provide idea option ive seen some ppl use in tutorials)

"FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ReflectionCache
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
  BUILD FAILED in 2s

(full message below):

```
[enter image description here][1]
Generating app in C:\Users\Jason\Downloads\test
Executing 'C:\Users\Jason\Downloads\test/gradlew.bat clean --no-daemon'
To honour the JVM settings for this build a new JVM will be forked. Please consider using the daemon: https://docs.gradle.org/5.4.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html.
Daemon will be stopped at the end of the build stopping after processing
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.VMPluginFactory.<clinit>(VMPluginFactory.java:43)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.GroovyClassValueFactory.<clinit>(GroovyClassValueFactory.java:35)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.<clinit>(ClassInfo.java:109)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ReflectionCache.getCachedClass(ReflectionCache.java:95)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ReflectionCache.<clinit>(ReflectionCache.java:39)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.registerMethods(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:209)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.<init>(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:107)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.<init>(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:85)
    at groovy.lang.GroovySystem.<clinit>(GroovySystem.java:36)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.<clinit>(InvokerHelper.java:86)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.getDefaultMetaClass(GroovyObjectSupport.java:59)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.<init>(GroovyObjectSupport.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.extensibility.DefaultExtraPropertiesExtension.<init>(DefaultExtraPropertiesExtension.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.extensibility.DefaultConvention.<init>(DefaultConvention.java:48)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultConvention.<init>(DefaultConvention.java:28)
    at org.gradle.internal.extensibility.ExtensibleDynamicObject.<init>(ExtensibleDynamicObject.java:60)
    at org.gradle.internal.instantiation.MixInExtensibleDynamicObject.<init>(MixInExtensibleDynamicObject.java:34)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultSettings_Decorated.getAsDynamicObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.initialization.SettingsFactory.createSettings(SettingsFactory.java:58)
    at org.gradle.initialization.ScriptEvaluatingSettingsProcessor.process(ScriptEvaluatingSettingsProcessor.java:60)
    at org.gradle.initialization.PropertiesLoadingSettingsProcessor.process(PropertiesLoadingSettingsProcessor.java:37)
    at org.gradle.initialization.SettingsEvaluatedCallbackFiringSettingsProcessor.process(SettingsEvaluatedCallbackFiringSettingsProcessor.java:34)
    at org.gradle.initialization.RootBuildCacheControllerSettingsProcessor.process(RootBuildCacheControllerSettingsProcessor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.initialization.BuildOperationSettingsProcessor$2.call(BuildOperationSettingsProcessor.java:50)
    at org.gradle.initialization.BuildOperationSettingsProcessor$2.call(BuildOperationSettingsProcessor.java:47)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.initialization.BuildOperationSettingsProcessor.process(BuildOperationSettingsProcessor.java:47)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultSettingsLoader.findSettingsAndLoadIfAppropriate(DefaultSettingsLoader.java:104)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultSettingsLoader.findAndLoadSettings(DefaultSettingsLoader.java:45)
    at org.gradle.initialization.SettingsAttachingSettingsLoader.findAndLoadSettings(SettingsAttachingSettingsLoader.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.composite.CommandLineIncludedBuildSettingsLoader.findAndLoadSettings(CommandLineIncludedBuildSettingsLoader.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.composite.ChildBuildRegisteringSettingsLoader.findAndLoadSettings(ChildBuildRegisteringSettingsLoader.java:47)
    at org.gradle.internal.composite.CompositeBuildSettingsLoader.findAndLoadSettings(CompositeBuildSettingsLoader.java:35)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$LoadBuild.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:277)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.loadSettings(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:202)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:147)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:134)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.execute(GradleBuildController.java:58)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.execute(GradleBuildController.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$3.create(GradleBuildController.java:82)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$3.create(GradleBuildController.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:183)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:55)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:31)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.java:58)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:51)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:45)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:78)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:78)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:68)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:38)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:60)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:32)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:48)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:62)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:81)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:295)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ReflectionCache

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Done!
To import in Eclipse: File -> Import -> Gradle -> Gradle Project
To import to Intellij IDEA: File -> Open -> build.gradle
To import to NetBeans: File -> Open Project...
```

Comment: Hello, which version of java do you use ?  
It seem the problem come from gradle

Comment: Does it work if you run it with graddle?
Click on icon next to green RunButton (To the left) -> EditConfigurations -> Add New Configuration(plus sign) -> Gradle 
for name use -> whathever you like,
for graddle project choose -> :desktop option
for task type -> run
click OK, and try to run this configuration

Comment: Same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62684765/7487013